# Place Image Outside margins

Tags: graphics, margins, templates

I'm writing a technical manual and I'm using this template:

```
% %
% LAYOUT_E.TEX - Short description of REFMAN.CLS
%                                       99-03-20
%
%  Updated for REFMAN.CLS (LaTeX2e)
%
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{refart}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
% ifthen wird vom Bild von N.Beebe gebraucht!

\def\bs{\char'134 } % backslash in \tt font.
\newcommand{\ie}{i.\,e.,}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.\,g..}
\DeclareRobustCommand\cs[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}

\title{Changing the layout with \LaTeX}
\author{EDV-Zentrum der TU Wien, Abt.~Digitalrechenanlage \\
Hubert Partl \\
1988-10-04   \\
English translation by\\
Axel Kielhorn\thanks{a.kielhorn@web.de}\\
1999-03-20   \\
H27.0 --- Version 1}

\date{}
\emergencystretch1em  %

\pagestyle{myfootings}
\markboth{Changing the layout with \textrm{\LaTeX}}%
         {Changing the layout with \textrm{\LaTeX}}

\makeindex 

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\begin{document}

\maketitle



\printindex

\end{document}
```

I want to add some picture, quite big, and I'm looking for how to use a different margin for the pictures so as to display larger images.

Thaks for the help.

BR,
Federico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

[image]

with help of package `changepage`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{refart}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
% ifthen wird vom Bild von N.Beebe gebraucht!
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}         %%%% added, in real document delete option "demo"
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}     %%%% added

\def\bs{\char'134 } % backslash in \tt font.
\newcommand{\ie}{i.\,e.,}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.\,g..}
\DeclareRobustCommand\cs[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}

\title{Changing the layout with \LaTeX}
\author{EDV-Zentrum der TU Wien, Abt.~Digitalrechenanlage \\
Hubert Partl \\
1988-10-04   \\
English translation by\\
Axel Kielhorn\thanks{a.kielhorn@web.de}\\
1999-03-20   \\
H27.0 --- Version 1}

\date{}
\emergencystretch1em  %

\pagestyle{myfootings}
\markboth{Changing the layout with \textrm{\LaTeX}}%
         {Changing the layout with \textrm{\LaTeX}}
\makeindex
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-\marginparwidth}{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my-figure}
\caption{}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Federico, which text? text which i added is wrap correctly, for other is responsible your document class.

Comment: @Federico, sorry, i don't understand you. it seems that you have new problem, which is not mentioned in your question. please, edit your question and show us, what you doing. now it is not clear.

Comment: Thanks Zarko! You solved my problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: I have one more question, how can I force the image position? I tried with [h!] but it doesn't work. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Federico, you should never use just `h!`. with it LaTeX is not enabled to move figure to the next page, if on inserted page haven't enough space.  see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat